# Looping for loop in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code.

```
    for idx in range(len(networks)):
        net_ = networks[idx]
        lastId=0
        for layerUptID in range(len(net_[1])):
            retNet,lastId=cn_.UpdateTwoConvLayers(deepcopy(net_),lastId)
            networks.append(retNet)
            if(lastId==-1):
               break
```

`networks` has only one net at the beginning.

After running the line `retNet,lastId=cn_.UpdateTwoConvLayers(deepcopy(net_),lastId)`, I have additional six nets and appended to `networks`.

So after this  `lastId ==-1`, go back to `first for loop` with `len(networks) is 7`.

For the next `idx, idx=1` and continue.

Then, len(networks) is 13. Then go back to `first for loop`.
After this, the first for loop breaks.
I am expecting to continue for `idx is 2`, but it breaks.

What could be the issue?

Comment: can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? as it is written now it is hard to tell what's wrong, my guess that you are mutating `list` while iterating and expecting that its length in line `for idx in range(len(networks)):` will change as well?

Comment: do you mean it breaks because `lastId==-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try using a WHILE loop instead of FOR loop, the break statement would be check if the loop is on the last item in 'networks' collection.
This way the network length would be calculated in each loop iteration

Answer (score 0):

For starters: Iterating, or looping, over the list (or data) you're editing is bad practice. Keep that in mind while coding.

This means if you plan to edit what you're looping on, in your case `networks`, then you're going to have a bad time looping over it. I would advise to break it up into two code parts:

The first part creates a new list of whatever it is you want WHILE looping.
The second part replaces the list you've used to generate what you wanted.

Another thing which could go wrong is `net_[i]` may not be set up for some i, and you're trying to access it here:

> ```
>     for layerUptID in range(len(net_[1])):
> ```

What if there is nothing in net_[1]?

To avoid these errors, usually verifying your data is a great way to start. If it is not null, then proceed, otherwise, print an error.

This is what I can think of. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your problem is that you've added new elements to `networks`, i.e. have increased length of `networks` and expect that `for`-loop will pick up this changes, well it's not, let's look at following snippet

```
elements = [1]

indices = range(len(elements))
for index in indices:
    print('index is', index)
    elements.append(2)
    print('elements count is', len(elements))
    print('indices count is', len(indices))
```

outputs are

```
index is 0
elements count is 2
indices count is 1
```

so as we can see despite the fact that length of `elements` list has changed, `range` object which is used in `for`-loop has not. This happens because `len` returns `int` object which are immutable, so when you change `list` length its length becomes different object and `range` function has no idea about this changes.

Finally, we can use `while` loop here like

```
while networks:
    net_ = networks.pop()
    lastId = 0
    for layerUptID in range(len(net_[1])):
        retNet, lastId = cn_.UpdateTwoConvLayers(deepcopy(net_), lastId)
        networks.append(retNet)
        if lastId == -1:
            break
```